# Selecting items in a combobox using Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Which Selenium Webdriver command is used for selecting items from combobox in Java?

I mean when we want to select one item from a Combobox but this element is not an instance of `Select` class, e.g., element found by commands like this

```
driver.findElement(By.id(elementId))
```

Comment: Google for: select combobox selenium

Comment: @dzieciou Did you actually google it? It takes you to a stack overflow post. Just because something is simple doesn't mean it isn't of value. The only thing I see wrong with the post is that it isn't immediately clear what the user's prior effort in solving the problem is, although I suspect that's what the last sentence is for.

Comment: @corsiKa, yes, I googled for it and it took me to the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924550/selenium-webdriver-to-select-combo-box-item post that answers the question, i.e., it "select one item from Combobox" that "is not select". I've never said simple questions aren't valueable, I just demonstrated **a way to find an answer**. If you want to discuss "How much prior research effort is expected before asking a question?" we could talk about this on meta. We could also discuss there whether we want to duplicate questions from other SE sites.

Comment: @user6261, I updated your question trying to clarify it. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a Select element instead of a simple WebElement.

```
Select selectObject = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id(elementId)));
selectObject.selectByValue("Item1"); // Assuming you have an element with value Item1 in your combo box
```